# Difference between password expiration and account expiration

Tags: access-control

If a password expires, the user can't access the account. If the account expires, the user can't access the account...

So, what's the difference? Just that in the case of an expired account, I'd need to enable it back?

Comment: Difference *where*?

Comment: @TerryChia the goal of prohibiting the access of an user after an specific time.

Comment: I know... *what* application are you talking about..? There is no reasonable answer for this question as it is very implementation dependent.

Comment: With an expired password there is usually a way to set a new password. How this process works depends on the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think password expiration and account expiration are two differents means to achieve the same goal, that is to prevent someone to log in. However, they are used in different context and for different needs.

Password expiration is used when you want to force someone to renew their password at a specific interval (maybe 90 days) but you want the account to stay enabled. The user will be prompted to change his password and the next logon.

Account expiration should be used in another context. For example if you hire a contractor for 6 months and you want the account to be disabled at the end of the contract, you can set an account expiration at a fixed date and you won't have to be concerned about removing access to this contractor when the contract is finished since the account will be automatically disabled.